# Hyperledger Indy - What's the difference between Trust Anchor and ENDORSER?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

I read
https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/master/docs/getting-started/indy-walkthrough.md and https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-node/blob/master/docs/source/auth_rules.md.

I think `Trust Anchor` , `ENDORSER` are have the same role, but I don't know the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an SDK point of view Trust Anchor equals Endorser, meaning that a Trust Anchor is fact an Endorser, but in a broader sense and looking up the Sovrin Dictionary a Trust Anchor is an entity like an a Credential Issuer (eg:Government,University,Company ecc..) that is an authoritative institution.

[Source](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/INDY-1950) and
[Source](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gfIz5TT0cNp2kxGMLFXr19x1uoZsruUe_0glHst2fZ8/edit#) page 64

Actually while trying to do some implementation with the Java Wrapper I've seen that in the method buildNymRequestuildNymRequest(String submitterDid,....,String role) if putting in the role="TRUST_ANCHOR" actually it will be translated to ENDORSER in the NYM transaction ( I check the transaction using indyscan https://github.com/Patrik-Stas/indyscan).
You may also want to check out my implementation (work in progress) of some operations in Java.
https://github.com/caltr98/IndyWorkings

If you've found a better solution on the Trust_Anchor/Endorser debacle please let me know.